# imagemagick compare pdf shows antialias differences

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two pdf files generated from the same `docx` file on different machines using LibreOffice. I want to compare them with imagemagick to make sure they have the same data and the layout also has not changed.

First, I convert both to png for this:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -background white -alpha remove output.png
```

Then I use the `compare` command to check for differences.

```
compare -verbose -metric AE -fuzz 10% output1.png output2.png diff.png
```

However, I still see some minor differences around the edges of the texts in the `diff.png` file. (similar to the image [in this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/imagemagick/comments/md0kh4/compare_pdf_shows_antialiasing_differences/)).

[image: noise around edges of text]

How can we fine-tune the comparison so this noise would be ignored but comparison would still detech more significant changes?

Comment: Your conversion to PNG may be slightly different if different versions of Ghostscript are being used.

Comment: Not tested: two things I would try: either apply a light (2-3px) median blur to both images before comparison or compare pixelized versions.